# Use component props in onClick redux-thunk dispatch React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-props

Trying to use props from `<button>` of component in the dispatch of a redux-thunk function that has been set up for Async process but I can't quite get how to use both props and the function (that's being connected to the component through react-redux `connect` in the `mapDispatchToProps`) but I just can't figure out how to call both the props and the function.

```
function loadData(dispatch, medium) {
    console.log(dispatch)
    return dispatch({type: 'LOADING_COMPONENT'})

  return axios.get(`/professionals/${medium}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      data => dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_SOME_DATA_SUCCESS', data }),
      err => dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_SOME_DATA_FAILURE', err })
    );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    LogInClick : () => dispatch(loadData()),
  }
}


const LoginButtons = ({props, LogInClick}) => (
    <button onClick={() => LogInClick(props.medium)} type="button">{props.buttonName}</button>
)


const LoginConnect = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginButtons)
```

And Then I export that and try to call it so it can be reused in the render file like

```
<LoginConnect medium='suhhhh' buttonName='To log in to suhhh'/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing your problem or not, but it seems like you're always returning the result of `dispatch()` in your `loadData()` function, meaning the axios call would never get called.

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadData(dispatch, medium) {
    console.log(dispatch)
    return dispatch({type: 'LOADING_COMPONENT'})

  return axios.get(`/professionals/${medium}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      data => dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_SOME_DATA_SUCCESS', data }),
      err => dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_SOME_DATA_FAILURE', err })
    );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    LogInClick : () => dispatch(loadData()),
  }
}


const LoginButtons = ({medium, buttonName, LogInClick}) => (
    <button onClick={() => LogInClick(medium)} type="button">{buttonName}</button>
)


const LoginConnect = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginButtons)
```

This should work !! actually connect merges mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps into this.props. Read this documenation for better understanding https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a function, which **redux-thunk** will then call with **dispatch** as an argument.

You can then call dispatch from that returned function:

```
function loadData(medium) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_COMPONENT' })

    axios.get(`/professionals/${medium}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        data => dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_SOME_DATA_SUCCESS', data }),
        err => dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_SOME_DATA_FAILURE', err })
      )
  }
}
```

Your **LogInClick** function can then take an argument which can be passed into **loadData**:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    LogInClick: (medium) => dispatch(loadData(medium)),
  }
}

const LoginButtons = (props) => (
  <button onClick={() => props.LogInClick(props.medium)} type="button">{props.buttonName}</button>
)
```

I hope this helps.